# Why a class does not implement ISerializable interface violates MissingSerializationConstructorRule

Tags: c#, serializable

We have sonar reports that says many of the classes in our projects violates the [MissingSerializationConstructorRule](https://github.com/spouliot/gendarme/wiki/Gendarme.Rules.Serialization.MissingSerializationConstructorRule%282.10%29), however neither the class nor its base class implement any of the Iserializable interface, anyone has any idea why?

for example, sonar says:

```
public class CommentPage : RmdsPublicationPage, ICommentPage 
    { 
 *MissingSerializationConstructorRule    
 The required constructor for ISerializable is not present in this type.* 
    public CommentPage() 
    { 
        this["COMMENTTXT"] = null;
```

where the corresponding class is

```
public class CommentPage : RmdsPublicationPage, ICommentPage
{
    public CommentPage()
    {
        // do something
    }
    public void Update(string comment)
    {
        //something else
    }
}
```

Two interfaces does not implement ISerializable either, i.e.

```
public class RmdsPublicationPage : Dictionary<string, object>, IRmdsPublicationPage

public interface IRmdsPublicationPage : IDictionary<string, object>, IDisposable
```

Comment: What about `ICommentPage`? You haven't posted that.

Comment: Any child class that derive from a ISerializable must implement the special constructor, otherwise they won't be Deserializable correctly. Dictionary does, so should your child classes from it.

Comment: Ah, thank you guys, i was looking into IDictionary not the dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dictionary(TKey, TValue)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) implements ISerializable

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(false)]
public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, 
    ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IDictionary, ICollection, 
    IReadOnlyDictionary<TKey, TValue>, IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, 
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable, ISerializable, 
    IDeserializationCallback
```